# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

To show a custom error message, I wrote the following simple code in the Controller:

```
if (rValue == -1)
{
   throw new ApplicationException("An error occured.");
}
```

This works fine in localhost. But when installed in the production IIS server, I am gettnig an error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo',
>       but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'workTable.Models.SchedulerModel.

I am using C#/razor/MVC3. Getting the same error when I throw the Excepton from .cshtml file. How can I fix this?

Comment: Define "fix". What do you want to happen?

Comment: Related [Why does System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo get passed to my views?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997396/argh-why-does-system-web-mvc-handleerrorinfo-get-passed-to-my-views)

Comment: @CodeCaster: I need to show my custom error message. Now in the production server, I am getting the error message that is shown above.

Comment: can you post some more code to elaborate your problem ?