# MVC custom error code in Global.asax.cs Application_Error not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I have the following global error handling setup for a webapp.

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    //log error
    _logger.Error("something bad happened", Server.GetLastError());

    //clear error
    Server.ClearError();

    //redirect to error page
    Response.RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "services", action = "error" });
}
```

Services controller with Error Action. **This view uses the ErrorModel class as the model.**

```
public ActionResult Error()
{
    return View(new ErrorModel{ Message = "nothing really happened go to bed" });
}
```

General view:

```
public ActionResult General()
{
    throw new Exception("Exception XYZ");
}
```

When I debug the application using VS F5, and go to `/general` view, the correct exception gets logged (`Exception XYZ`).

But when testing the published IIS webapp, and going to `/general` view, a different, unexpected exception is getting logged:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'MyWebsite.Models.Services.ErrorModel'.

The `Exception XYX` does not get logged at all. The correct `Error` view with the correct error message (`nothing really happened go to bed`) does get shown.

What am I doing wrong? How do I make sure `Exception XYZ` gets logged?

I don't intend to use `HandleErrorAttribute` or `override void OnException` in the controller at this time.

**EDIT**
Seems like this issue is already discussed in 2010 on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997396/argh-why-does-system-web-mvc-handleerrorinfo-get-passed-to-my-views)

Comment: Go to iis-> select your project->explore->open Views folder->find your view and check model

Comment: Also you can run VS as admin and debug application which is already published to iis. Debug -> Attach to procces->check "Show processes from all users" find your process(type w3wp)->Attach